# Return 403 for specific paths in Wordpress

Tags: htaccess, hacked

my site has been compromised and now crawlers try to index thousands of pages that no longer exist. I would like to return a 403 for these attempts because the query limit of the hosting has been reached. I was trying to achieve that by `.htaccess` rules, but they basically don't work (probably wordpress override them?). The most hit address is:
`/mds.php?[regex]`

How to block them from .htaccess configuration (or other way, to return 403 error)

Comment: What URL(s) are you trying to block? What rule(s) are you attempting to use? Where exactly in your `.htaccess` file are you putting this rule(s)?